# What is the explanation for the appearance of airplanes hovering?

Tags: commercial-aviation, stall, wind, crosswind, hover

A few weeks ago, I saw a plane that appeared to be hovering in the air. It was a large commercial airliner. It was not a windy day, land speeds of 24km/h max that day, about 5km/h at the time I saw it (according to meteored). The trees were not moving at all. We were not too far from the airport, it was close enough that it looked like it was landing soon. I would like to understand what I saw under these specific conditions because there is no possibility that the frontal speed was going at the speed of an airplane. What am I missing?

I of course looked it up on YouTube and found many others have seen exactly the same. For approximate height, see the following video at minute 8:22

Thank you!!!

Comment: enough w/ these hoax videos please

Comment: Mentour has a very good video on the effect [Here](https://youtu.be/3osSwf7dgUI)

Comment: That is actually very helpful and complete info. Will study now. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **perspective**.

Airliners, even smaller ones, are very large relative to most flying objects we're used to seeing (namely, birds). When they are not literally *on the ground* it is very hard to get proper perspective on their actual speed relative to us, and it looks like they are "hanging" in midair.

In addition, planes are going their slowest speed when they are close to landing, which furthers the phenomenon.